# Image upload and showing errors in php jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to change profile image with the code below. It permits few formats and size less than 2mb, In case it's not so it will give error. Upload works well but something is wrong with errors, on choosing an image type that is not permitted by code or image is more than 2mb it neither uploads image nor shows error just progress bar completes its process but no image is changed or uploaded to database nor any error is shown, I want to have error when image is above 2mb or format not permitted by code.

`imageupload.php`

```
if ($_FILES['image_upload_file']["error"] > 0) {
    $output['error']= "Error in File";
}
elseif (!in_array($_FILES['image_upload_file']["type"], $allowedImageType)) {
$output['error']= "You can only upload JPG, PNG and GIF file";
}
elseif (round($_FILES['image_upload_file']["size"] / 1024) > 4096) {
$output['error']= "You can upload file size up to 4 MB";
} else {
    /*create directory with 777 permission if not exist - start*/
    createDir(IMAGE_SMALL_DIR);
    createDir(IMAGE_MEDIUM_DIR);
    /*create directory with 777 permission if not exist - end*/
    $path[0] = $_FILES['image_upload_file']['tmp_name'];
    $file = pathinfo($_FILES['image_upload_file']['name']);
    $fileType = $file["extension"];
    $desiredExt='jpg';
    $fileNameNew = rand(333, 999) . time() . ".$desiredExt";
    $path[1] = IMAGE_MEDIUM_DIR . $fileNameNew;
    $path[2] = IMAGE_SMALL_DIR . $fileNameNew;

if (createThumb($path[0], $path[1], $fileType, IMAGE_MEDIUM_SIZE, IMAGE_MEDIUM_SIZE,IMAGE_MEDIUM_SIZE)) {

if (createThumb($path[1], $path[2],"$desiredExt", IMAGE_SMALL_SIZE, IMAGE_SMALL_SIZE,IMAGE_SMALL_SIZE)) {
    $output['status']=TRUE;
    $output['image_medium']= $path[1];
    $output['image_small']= $path[2];
  }
 }
}
echo json_encode($output);
}
?>
```

`settings.php`

```
<script>
$(document).on('change', '#image_upload_file', function () {
var progressBar = $('.progressBar'), bar = $('.progressBar .bar'), percent = $('.progressBar .percent');
$('#image_upload_form').ajaxForm({
beforeSend: function() {
progressBar.fadeIn();
    var percentVal = '0%';
    bar.width(percentVal)
    percent.html(percentVal);
},
uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
    var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
    bar.width(percentVal)
    percent.html(percentVal);
},
success: function(html, statusText, xhr, $form) {   
obj = $.parseJSON(html);  
if(obj.status){   
  var percentVal = '100%';
  bar.width(percentVal)
  percent.html(percentVal);
  $("#imgArea>img").prop('src',obj.image_medium);     
}else{
  alert(obj.error);
}
},
complete: function(xhr) {
progressBar.fadeOut();      
} 
}).submit();    
});
</script>
```

form

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="imageupload.php" method="post" name="image_upload_form" id="image_upload_form">
 <div id="imgArea"><img src="<?php echo $profile_photo; ?>">
 <div class="progressBar">
 <div class="bar"></div>
 <div class="percent">0%</div>
 </div>
 <div id="imgChange" style="background: url("../img/overlay.png") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);bottom: 0;color: #FFFFFF;display: block;height: 30px;left: 0;line-height: 32px;position: absolute;width: 100%;"><p>Click on photo to change</p>
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="image_upload_file" id="image_upload_file">
 </div>
 </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console? Also not 2 MB, but you have in your code 4 MB... Where do you have calling of `imageupload.php` in your jQuery code?

Comment: @Legionar thats in my form codes updated now